# how to have a Count when using Groupby?

Tags: mysql, database

I have got a column name country in which there are 3 entries which are shown below. In each countries i have set of people working in it in a different column. I want a count query which can count how people are working in each country in a single query.

```
country
________
 India
 America
 China
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT country,COUNT(*)  
FROM table        
GROUP BY country;
```